# Problem in compiling and running code in VS Code

Tags: terminal, visual-studio-code

I have been working on VS Code early this early untill last month when I faced this issue of not compiling and running my code due to some security threat given by McAfee

Here are the image attachments
[image]

I don't what is causing this problem, **if anyone could help me it would be a lot of beneficial** since I have many assignments and I don't like online editors that much

Answer (score 1):

Probably as you are compiling code (generating binary files) McAfee thinks you are generating malware (as an attacker would do) preventing it to complete, why don't you just temporarily disable the AntiVirus and test?

Comment: will try that and let you know @Reynoldo Aceves